# Excel VBA - msoEffectBlur

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone help me with following action?
I want to loop 100 pictures in excel sheet and set them to Blur with a specific Radius value.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 412").Fill.PictureEffects.Insert msoEffectBlur
```

This statement is working but I don't know how to add a radius value.
Also not sure how to loop through all the pictures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I upvoted the answer of **antca230** because it shows how to set the radius. However, the rest of the code will not work, there are some issues:

**(a)** It loops over all shapes of the Activesheet using the variable `picture`, however within the loop it uses another variable, and that will work always on the first shape.

**(b)** It will apply the effect to all shapes, but that will cause issues if you have other shapes (like a simple box) on the sheet. You should check the type of the shape before applying the effect

```
Dim picture As Shape
For Each picture In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If picture.Type = msoPicture Then
        picture.Fill.PictureEffects.Insert msoEffectBlur
        picture.Fill.PictureEffects(1).EffectParameters(1).Value = 4
    End If
Next picture
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this? Been a long time since I used VBA

```
Dim picture As Shape
   For Each picture In ActiveSheet.Shapes
      Dim opic As Shape
      Set opic = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
      opic.Fill.PictureEffects.Insert (msoEffectBlur)
      opic.Fill.PictureEffects(1).EffectParameters(1).Value = 20
   Next picture
```